# Join two tables based on nearby timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, left-join

Table1 (1422 rows)

```
 sn1     |       dateee        | shift | linee
---------+---------------------+-------+-------
 8419404 | 2015-02-27 09:45:50 | D     |     2
 8419383 | 2015-02-27 09:46:10 | D     |     2
 8419410 | 2015-02-27 09:46:40 | D     |     2
 8419385 | 2015-02-27 09:50:40 | D     |     2
 8419412 | 2015-02-27 09:50:50 | D     |     2
 8419390 | 2015-02-27 09:51:30 | D     |     2
 8419414 | 2015-02-27 09:52:00 | D     |     2
 8419387 | 2015-02-27 09:52:20 | D     |     2
 8419416 | 2015-02-27 09:52:50 | D     |     2
 8419394 | 2015-02-27 09:57:10 | D     |     2
```

Table2 (824 rows)

```
id    | id2 |        timee
------+-----+---------------------
 1302 |     | 2015-02-27 09:46:11
 1303 |     | 2015-02-27 09:46:36
 1304 |     | 2015-02-27 09:50:37
 1305 |     | 2015-02-27 09:51:06
 1306 |     | 2015-02-27 09:51:31
 1307 |     | 2015-02-27 09:51:55
 1308 |     | 2015-02-27 09:52:20
 1309 |     | 2015-02-27 09:52:45
 1310 |     | 2015-02-27 09:57:05
```

I want to join these two tables (using left join) with nearby timestamps.
`table1` is first step and `table2` is second step in production process.

In my desired table dateee(from `table1`) and timee(from `table2`) should be very nearby. I want to correlate `sn1` and `id` based on the nearby timestamp.

Comment: What would the result table look like?

Comment: i would like to have a result table with all columns from two tables , but the timestamp should be nearby...

Comment: Define "nearby" exactly, please.

Comment: timestamp in table 1 is from scanner1 and timestamp in table 2 is from scanner 2. ... timestamp in table 2 should be grater than timestamp in table 1 and close to it

Comment: The definition of "nearby" should be in the question.

Answer (score 8):

"Nearby" is rather fuzzy.
To join `table2` where `timee` lies within 10 seconds of `dateee` in the future:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
LEFT   JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.timee BETWEEN t1.dateee
                                      AND t1.dateee + interval '10 sec';
```

- The `LEFT JOIN` keeps rows from `table1` in the result, even without match in `table2`.
- There can be multiple matches, so that each row from the base tables can be returned multiple times in various combinations.

#### Alternative

To join each rows in `table1` to the row with with the next higher timestamp. *Exactly* one row in the result per row on `table1`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   table2 t2
   WHERE  t2.timee >= t1.dateee
   ORDER  BY t2.timee
   LIMIT  1
   ) ON TRUE;
```

An index on `(timee)` is essential for performance.

Comment: thank you very much for the help....but iam facing these error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1: ...dateee + interval '1 sec and t1.dateee - interval '1 sec;

Comment: The time frame in `BETWEEN` was backwards. But that's futile with your new definition. I added another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this will work

```
select * 
from 
    Table1 t1, 
    Table2 t2,
    (select 
        a.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by a.sn1 order by a.mt) rn
    from
        (select 
            q.sn1, 
            w.id id, 
            min(abs(q.dateee - w.timee)) mt
        from 
            Table1 q, 
            Table2 w 
        group by q.sn1, w.id
        ) a
    ) mysort
where 
mysort.rn = 1 and mysort.sn1 = t1.sn1 and mysort.id=t2.id
```

but beware large data sets