# Pandas Join Two Tables Based On Time Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to join two tables in Pandas based on timestamp.  Basically the structure looks something like this:

Table 2

```
Timestamp          Truck     MineX           MineY
2016-08-27 01:10    CT77    -11346.36655    -650404.405
2016-08-27 01:12    CT45    -11596.88137    -648294.056
2016-08-27 01:13    CT67    -11953.16118    -648325.114
2016-08-27 01:13    CT75    -11326.54075    -650447.462
2016-08-27 01:14    CT79    -11380.27834    -650425.968
2016-08-27 01:15    CT26    -9493.153286    -652313.633
2016-08-27 01:16    CT73    -11527.47602    -650210.723
2016-08-27 01:16    CT40    -11596.90867    -648260.214
2016-08-27 01:17    CT26    -9493.153286    -652313.633
2016-08-27 01:17    CT80    -11363.34558    -650385.959
2016-08-27 01:17    CT72    -11527.47355    -650213.8
```

Table 1

```
Truck   LoadLocation    Tonnes  ArriveTimestamp
CT70    338-001       261         2016-02-21 00:23
CT66    338-001       271         2016-02-21 00:31
CT62    338-001       264         2016-02-21 00:45
CT73    338-001       254         2016-02-21 00:54
CT71    338-001       250         2016-02-21 01:04
CT39    338-001       182.172     2016-02-21 01:11
CT62    338-001       285         2016-02-21 01:19
CT70    338-001       282         2016-02-21 01:25
CT73    338-001       250         2016-02-21 01:30
CT73    338-001       275         2016-02-21 01:35
CT64    338-001       253         2016-02-21 01:42
```

Table 1 and Table 2 need to be joined, where Timestamp and ArriveTimeStamp are within one minute of each other, and the Truck ID is the same.   A left join is preferred where records from Table 2 are thrown out if there is no match

Comment: I think you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491840/merging-two-pandas-dataframes-on-nearest-time-stamp).

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for.  I want to throw out Table 2 results that are not within the specified time condition.  The mentioned question joins according to nearest item

Comment: Please check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), I have some idea but without data it is really hard.

Comment: Example data added...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Truck', how='left')
print (df)
   Truck LoadLocation   Tonnes     ArriveTimestamp           Timestamp  \
0   CT70      338-001  261.000 2016-02-21 00:23:00                 NaT   
1   CT66      338-001  271.000 2016-02-21 00:31:00                 NaT   
2   CT62      338-001  264.000 2016-02-21 00:45:00                 NaT   
3   CT73      338-001  254.000 2016-02-21 00:54:00 2016-08-27 01:16:00   
4   CT71      338-001  250.000 2016-02-21 01:04:00                 NaT   
5   CT39      338-001  182.172 2016-02-21 01:11:00                 NaT   
6   CT62      338-001  285.000 2016-02-21 01:19:00                 NaT   
7   CT70      338-001  282.000 2016-02-21 01:25:00                 NaT   
8   CT73      338-001  250.000 2016-02-21 01:30:00 2016-08-27 01:16:00   
9   CT73      338-001  275.000 2016-02-21 01:35:00 2016-08-27 01:16:00   
10  CT64      338-001  253.000 2016-02-21 01:42:00                 NaT   

          MineX       MineY  
0           NaN         NaN  
1           NaN         NaN  
2           NaN         NaN  
3  -11527.47602 -650210.723  
4           NaN         NaN  
5           NaN         NaN  
6           NaN         NaN  
7           NaN         NaN  
8  -11527.47602 -650210.723  
9  -11527.47602 -650210.723  
10          NaN         NaN
```

with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), where filter absolute differences in `datetimes` - sample return empty `DataFrame`:

```
print ((df.Timestamp - df.ArriveTimestamp).astype('timedelta64[s]'))
0            NaN
1            NaN
2            NaN
3     16244520.0
4            NaN
5            NaN
6            NaN
7            NaN
8     16242360.0
9     16242060.0
10           NaN
dtype: float64

print ((df.Timestamp - df.ArriveTimestamp).astype('timedelta64[s]').abs() < 60)
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
dtype: bool
Empty DataFrame

print (df[(df.Timestamp - df.ArriveTimestamp).astype('timedelta64[s]').abs() < 60])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Truck, LoadLocation, Tonnes, ArriveTimestamp, Timestamp, MineX, MineY]
Index: []
```

Comment: Will this retain the amount of rows in Table 1?  For some reason my PC crashes when I include this code.  Trying to figure out why

Comment: The code is using an enormous amount of memory, reason why PC is crashing.  It returns a table with billions of rows due to the amount of permutations and combinations of merging Table 1 and Table 2

Comment: You are right, unfortunately I have no other idea for better solution. Only you can try [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) for merging or sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.merge(left=Table1,right=Table2, left_on=['TimeStamp1'], right_on=['TimeStamp2'])
```

Comment: where is the within one minute condition?

Comment: Can you post sample data and expected output?

Comment: Same as this sql question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28839524/join-two-tables-based-on-nearby-timestamps